# Postgres concurrency issue

Tags: postgresql

I wrote the following trigger to guarantee that the field 'filesequence' on the insert receives always the maximum value + 1, for one stakeholder.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_filesequence()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
  DECLARE
    lastSequence file.filesequence%TYPE;

  BEGIN
    IF (NEW.filesequence IS NULL) THEN

      PERFORM ''SELECT id FROM stakeholder WHERE id = NEW.stakeholder FOR UPDATE'';

      SELECT max(filesequence) INTO lastSequence FROM file WHERE stakeholder = NEW.stakeholder;

      IF (lastSequence IS NULL) THEN
        lastSequence = 0;
      END IF;

      lastSequence = lastSequence + 1;

      NEW.filesequence = lastSequence;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER file_update_filesequence BEFORE INSERT
  ON file FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  update_filesequence();
```

But I have repeated 'filesequence' on the database:

```
select id, filesequence, stakeholder from file where stakeholder=5273;
id      filesequence    stakeholder
6773    5               5273
6774    5               5273
```

By my undertanding, the SELECT... FOR UPDATE would LOCK two transactions on the same stakeholder, and then the second one would read the new 'filesequence'. But it is not working.

I made some tests on PgAdmin, executing the following:

```
BEGIN;
select id from stakeholder where id = 5273 FOR UPDATE;
```

And it realy LOCKED other records being inserted to the same stakeholder. Then it seems that the LOCK is working.

But when I run the application with concurrent uploads, I see then repeating.

Someone could help me in finding what is the issue with my trigger?

Thanks,
Douglas.

Comment: In plpgsql, doesn't that first BEGIN mark the start of a block, not the start of a transaction?

Comment: A personal question: where did you learn to use `PERFORM` like this? I saw a lot of people doing that, and I don't know why. (it is wrong, see my answer)...

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall', that `BEGIN` does not start a transaction, but on PostgreSQL a function is **always** called **inside a transaction**.

Comment: @MatheusOl I tryed to use SELECT and ignore the result, and received an exception on Java with the sugestion of using PERFORM. And I used it without undertanding the correct usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right. To get an autoincrement based on another field (let's say it designate to a group) you cannot use a sequence, then you have to lock the rows of that group before incrementing it.

The logic of your trigger function does that. But you have a misunderstood about the `PERFORM` operation. It supposed to be put instead of the `SELECT` keyword, so it does not receive an string as parameter. It means that when you do:

```
PERFORM 'SELECT id FROM stakeholder WHERE id = NEW.stakeholder FOR UPDATE';
```

The PL/pgSQL is actually executing:

```
SELECT 'SELECT id FROM stakeholder WHERE id = NEW.stakeholder FOR UPDATE';
```

And ignoring the result.

What you have to do on this line is:

```
PERFORM id FROM stakeholder WHERE id = NEW.stakeholder FOR UPDATE;
```

That is it, only change this line and you are done.